# Why is I cannot send packet of byte from separate thread to COM port in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm working on an application where I use specific protocol to send packet over COM port to a hardware. I have the protocol specifications document available. I'm able to send the packets using `WriteFile()`. Going through the protocol specs, I see that I must sent a specific packet every 50ms. I thought I could do this by having another thread sending this packet every 50ms so that I can do other read/write operations in the main thread. However when I try this it did not work (no TXD on RS422 adapter and not printing anything, I added `cout` to see if line is executed). Only way I could send packets was if the application was singlethreaded.

Here is the code:

```
void sendBootSignal(HANDLE h_Serial, byte packetArr[], DWORD size)
{
    DWORD dwWrite = 11;
    if (!WriteFile(h_Serial, packetArr, (DWORD)size, &dwWrite, NULL))
    {
        std::cout << "error while WriteFile" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "succesfully send boot packet" << std::endl;
    }
}

void bootThread(HANDLE h_Serial, byte packetArr[], DWORD size)
{
    while (true)
    {
        sendBootSignal(h_Serial, packetArr, size);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    h_Serial = CreateFile(L"COM3", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (h_Serial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            std::cout << "Serial Port not found" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "error while establishing communication" << std::endl;
    }

    DCB dcbSerialParam = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParam.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParam);

    if (!GetCommState(h_Serial, &dcbSerialParam))
    {
        std::cout << "error when getting comm state" << std::endl;
    }

    dcbSerialParam.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    dcbSerialParam.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParam.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParam.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcbSerialParam.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;

    if (!SetCommState(h_Serial, &dcbSerialParam))
    {
        std::cout << "error while setting comm state" << std::endl;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeout = { 0 };
    timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 60;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 60;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 15;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 60;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 8;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(h_Serial, &timeout))
    {
        std::cout << "timeout " << std::endl;
    }

    byte bootPacket[11] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    bootPacket[0] = 0x10;
    bootPacket[1] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[2] = 0x80;
    bootPacket[3] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[4] = 0x48;
    bootPacket[5] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[6] = 255;
    bootPacket[7] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[8] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[9] = 0x10;
    bootPacket[10] = 0x03;

    DWORD size = 11;
    sizeCalculator(bootPacket, size);
    checksumCalculator(bootPacket, size);
    std::thread t1(bootThread, h_Serial, bootPacket, size);


    while (true)
    {
        // do other things here
    }

    CloseHandle(h_Serial);
}
```

Is this approach incorrect? If yes, what would be a better approach to this problem?

---

##### EDIT 1

I found out that the reason why it was getting stuck was not because of `WriteFile()` rather the `std::cout`. The question at the end is still relevant. I'd appreciate if someone can comment on why cout in the else block of `sentBootSignal()` just stops the application.

---

##### EDIT 2

Restarting Visual Studio fixed the `cout` issue however I'm still wondering about the multithreading this problem. Appreciate the responses.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing to the same file handle concurrently. These operations are not atomic, and I would not expect it to behave predictably. Even using `std::cout` on multiple threads can be problematic and calls should be synchronized. Consider moving all of your COM port I/O onto the service thread and use a notifying queue to allow other threads to send data to the service thread for writing. The service thread can then handle all communication, including the "keep-alive" stuff at regular intervals when nothing else is in the queue, or however your protocol is supposed to operate.

Comment: I see, thank you for your comment, can you elaborate on "service thread"? Any specific meaning or terminology or a thread that handles only I/O.

Comment: It's just a general name to describe a thread that handles I/O, or any task really. Other names might be "worker" or "background" thread. However, I think there's nuances here. I would personally use "service" to describe something that off-loads I/O or manages a resource, "worker" for something that performs high-load computation, and "background" for something that performs intermittent or low-frequency tasks. Don't get caught up on that. Just my own mostly subconscious terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect your code to protect sending the data at least using a mutex.
The example also shows some C++ style alternatives to using "C" style arrays for sending the data

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <span>
#include <Windows.h>


class YourDevice
{
public:
    YourDevice() 
    {
        // open serial port etc...
    }

    ~YourDevice()
    {
        // close serial port etc...
    }

    // send a packet of N bytes
    // Note I use std::uint8_t instead of char to avoid confusion with strings (and signedness)
    // used when size is know at compile time
    template<DWORD N>
    void sendPacket(const std::uint8_t(&packet)[N])
    {
        // ensure only one thread can send a packet at a time
        std::scoped_lock lock(m_mtx);
        
        DWORD dwWrite = N;
        if (!WriteFile(m_serial, packet, N, &dwWrite, NULL))
        {
            std::cout << "error while WriteFile" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "succesfully send boot packet" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    // used when size is only known at runtime
    void SendPacket(std::span<int> packet)
    {
         // ensure only one thread can send a packet at a time
        std::scoped_lock lock(m_mtx);

        DWORD dwWrite = packet.size();
        if (!WriteFile(m_serial, packet.data(), packet.size(), &dwWrite, NULL))
        {
            std::cout << "error while WriteFile" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "succesfully send boot packet" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void sendBootSignal()
    {
        // the packed is a sequence of 11 bytes initialized with the values provided within the curly braces
        sendPacket({0x10, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x03});
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    HANDLE m_serial;

};

int main()
{
    YourDevice device;
    device.sendBootSignal();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The multithreading method is as follows:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
HANDLE h_Serial; byte packetArr[]; DWORD size;
void sendBootSignal(HANDLE h_Serial, byte packetArr[], DWORD size)
{
    DWORD dwWrite = 11;
    if (!WriteFile(h_Serial, packetArr, (DWORD)size, &dwWrite, NULL))
    {
        std::cout << "error while WriteFile" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "succesfully send boot packet" << std::endl;
    }
}
void bootThread(HANDLE h_Serial, byte packetArr[], DWORD size)
{
    while (true)
    {
        sendBootSignal(h_Serial, packetArr, size);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
    }
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    while (true)
    {
        sendBootSignal(h_Serial, packetArr, size);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
    }

    return 1;
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc2(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    h_Serial = CreateFile(L"COM3", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (h_Serial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            std::cout << "Serial Port not found" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "error while establishing communication" << std::endl;
    }

    DCB dcbSerialParam = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParam.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParam);

    if (!GetCommState(h_Serial, &dcbSerialParam))
    {
        std::cout << "error when getting comm state" << std::endl;
    }

    dcbSerialParam.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    dcbSerialParam.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParam.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParam.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcbSerialParam.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;

    if (!SetCommState(h_Serial, &dcbSerialParam))
    {
        std::cout << "error while setting comm state" << std::endl;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeout = { 0 };
    timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 60;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 60;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 15;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 60;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 8;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(h_Serial, &timeout))
    {
        std::cout << "timeout " << std::endl;
    }

    byte bootPacket[11] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    bootPacket[0] = 0x10;
    bootPacket[1] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[2] = 0x80;
    bootPacket[3] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[4] = 0x48;
    bootPacket[5] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[6] = 255;
    bootPacket[7] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[8] = 0x00;
    bootPacket[9] = 0x10;
    bootPacket[10] = 0x03;

    DWORD size = 11;
    sizeCalculator(bootPacket, size);
    checksumCalculator(bootPacket, size);
    std::thread t1(bootThread, h_Serial, bootPacket, size);


    while (true)
    {
        // do other things here
    }

    CloseHandle(h_Serial);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hThread[2];
    DWORD dWResult1;
    DWORD dWResult2;
    hThread[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
    hThread[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc2, NULL, 0, NULL);


    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hThread, true, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread[0], &dWResult1);
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread[1], &dWResult2);
    printf("Thread execution completed \n");
    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hThread[0]);
    CloseHandle(hThread[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely horrendous code. Just to name two issues: `1` When `CreateFileW()` fails there is no reason to continue. But that is exactly what the code does. `2` When constructing a `std::thread` with automatic storage duration you will want to make sure that it has run to completion prior to entering its d'tor. The code doesn't and rather accepts an exception thrown from a d'tor.

Comment: @IInspectable The code is not modified which provided by op. I don't fix it and do not have to. It even cannot pass the compile. You're so wise why don't you just point out it early behind the question.

Comment: *"The code is not modified \[...\]. I don't fix it and do not have to."* - If that is your stance, then why feel the need to propose an answer at all? You don't have anything of value to contribute, so just keep it at that and don't. That would certainly save me some reputation and moderation burden.